# Moving the mouse cursor (not just screen) in vim

Tags: vim, bsd

With my `.vimrc` under Linux I can scroll using my mouse wheel and the cursor itself goes up and down, shifting the lines shown on the screen if necessary.  Using the same `.vimrc` and `vim` installed from `pkg` on FreeBSD 12, I get different behavior: the mouse scrolls the entire screen all at once (the lines on the screen change as I scroll, but the cursor stays on the top line.)

How can I get the same mouse wheel / scrolling behavior under BSD with vim as I do in Linux?

Comment: There  are so many potential differences between your environments: Vim version, terminal emulator, etc. Moving your `vimrc` around is **not** a guarantee that you will get the same behaviour.